# When I am trying to upsample a dataset in R, no action is being performed

Tags: r

I am trying to upsample or oversample a dataset in R using "ovun.sample" function in ROSE package, no computation is being done.

```
mission <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
colnames(mission) <- c("Gen", "Age", "Key_Comp", "Weight", "Height", "Pulse", "HBP", "LBP",
                           "RR", "PMH", "HB", "Urea", "Creatinine", "Arrival", "Arrival_State",
                           "Admsn_Type", "C2H", "B2P", "Concession", "Actl_Amt", "Stay", 
                           "ICU_stay", "Ward_stay", "Implant", "Implant_Cost", "GRL")

library(caTools)
set.seed(123)

split <- sample.split(mission, SplitRatio = 0.7)

train <- subset(mission, split == T)
test <- subset(mission, split == F)
over <- ovun.sample(GRL ~.,data = train, method = "over", N = 254)$mission

over$GRL
"NULL"

table(over$GRL)
"< table of extent 0 >"
```

When I am running "over$GRL", I am getting "NULL" as response and when running "table(over$GRL)", I am getting "< table of extent 0 >" as result.
I am not able to oversample or undersample the dataset.
Could anyone help me out with this?

Comment: See `str(over)` to see what columns are available (assuming it's a data.frame-like structure).

Comment: In this line `over <- ovun.sample(GRL ~.,data = train, method = "over", N = 254)$mission`, try swapping the `$mission` at the end to `$data`.

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thank you for your reply. Appreciate it.

Comment: @meenaparam yes, it did.

Comment: Great, feel free to accept the answer below then so the question gets marked as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer from the comments, for completeness:

```
mission <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)
colnames(mission) <- c("Gen", "Age", "Key_Comp", "Weight", "Height", "Pulse", "HBP", "LBP",
                           "RR", "PMH", "HB", "Urea", "Creatinine", "Arrival", "Arrival_State",
                           "Admsn_Type", "C2H", "B2P", "Concession", "Actl_Amt", "Stay", 
                           "ICU_stay", "Ward_stay", "Implant", "Implant_Cost", "GRL")

library(caTools)
set.seed(123)

split <- sample.split(mission, SplitRatio = 0.7)

train <- subset(mission, split == T)
test <- subset(mission, split == F)

# this line was the problem - it should end $data, not $mission
over <- ovun.sample(GRL ~.,data = train, method = "over", N = 254)$data
```